# How to add/subtract time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, timezone

To get the current date and time im using the below code:

```
var currentTime = getFormatedDateTime(dateTime: Date())
```

i have to check if the current date and time is same as the selected timezone.
To get the Eastern Standard Time i'm using this code:

```
    TimeZone.ReferenceType.default = TimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")!
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.default
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    let strDate = formatter.string(from: Date())
    print("time : \(strDate)")
```

Can you help me to add/subtract time from the current time to the timezone?

Comment: Also, don't use time zone abbreviations.  They can be ambiguous (CST also is China Standard Time, etc.).  Use `TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")`

Comment: OK thank you @matt

Comment: @matt johnson none of the answers worked